# Playing from a SoundCloud MP3 streaming URL using Go?

Tags: audio, go, soundcloud, audio-streaming

I'm working with the SoundCloud API for a personal project. I'm trying to play from an MP3 streaming URL, which looks like this: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/179364585/stream

What options do I have in Go for streaming audio from the web?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Upon more research/asking around, I think I've found the answer to my own question. Someone on reddit pointed me to [GStreamer bindings for Go](https://github.com/ziutek/gst).